# Incremental number in shell script on each loop

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

echo SCRIPT: $0
echo "Enter Customer Order Ref (e.g. 100018)"
read P_CUST_ORDER_REF
echo "Enter DU Id (e.g. 100018)"
read P_DU_ID

P_ORDER_ID=${P_CUST_ORDER_REF}${P_DU_ID}


#Loop through all XML files in the current directory
for f in *.xml
do
  #Increment P_CUST_ORDER_REF here
done
```

Inside the for loop how can i increment P_CUST_ORDER_REF by 1 every time it loops

```
so it READs 10000028 uses it on first loop
2nd 10000029
3rd 10000030
4th 10000031
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
((P_CUST_ORDER_REF+=1))
```

or

```
let P_CUST_ORDER_REF+=1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
P_CUST_ORDER_REF=$((P_CUST_ORDER_REF+1))
```

Comment: +1 for portability.  Note that you can also do: `: $(( P_CUST_ORDER_REF += 1 ))` or use a `++` operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the post-increment operator:

```
(( P_CUST_ORDER_REF++ ))
```

I recommend:

- habitually using lowercase or mixed case variable names to avoid potential name collision with shell or environment variables
- quoting all variables when they are expanded
- usually using `-r` with read to prevent backslashes from being interpreted as escapes
- validating user input

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
is_pos_int () {
    [[ $1 =~ ^([1-9][0-9]*|0)$ ]]
}

echo "SCRIPT: $0"

read -rp 'Enter Customer Order Ref (e.g. 100018)' p_cust_order_ref
is_pos_int "$p_cust_order_ref"

read -rp 'Enter DU Id (e.g. 100018)' p_du_id
is_pos_int "$p_dui_id"

p_order_id=${p_cust_order_ref}${p_du_id}

#Loop through all XML files in the current directory
for f in *.xml
do
    (( p_cust_order_ref++ ))
done
```