# While read line and print line number

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop

I want to print the line number that is being processed with my "while read line" loop like this:

```
while read line; do
   echo <line number>
   <my loop command that is working well>
done < myfile
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incremental number in shell script on each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999541/incremental-number-in-shell-script-on-each-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a counter above the loop

```
counter = 0
while read line; do
   echo counter
   <my loop command that is working well>
   counter = counter + 1
done < myfile
```

Comment: This contains many errors, both syntactic and conceptual. Probably test your solution before posting it, especially if you are new to the shell. Maybe also try http://shellcheck.net/ but it can't report problems e.g. when you `echo` something different than what you probably intended.